# Way to decrease column length in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2

Is there a way to decrease the column length in DB2?

Say I have a table temp with column `col1` defined as `VARCHAR(80)`. I want to reduce it to `VARCHAR(60)`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In DB2 9.7 for Linux/UNIX/Windows, you can use the ALTER TABLE statement to reduce the length of a column, *assuming that no values in the column exceed the new column size*:

```
ALTER TABLE temp
    ALTER COLUMN col1 SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(60);
```

If any values in the column exceed the desired size you must handle that first.

In previous versions of DB2 for Linux/UNIX/Windows, you could not utilize this method to reduce the size of the column.  You either had to drop/recreate the table, or go through a process of adding a column, copying data, and removing the old column.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to Ian's answer and [Clockwork-Muse's remark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579075/way-to-decrease-column-length-in-db2#comment12160308_9580116):

While it is possible, as Ian pointed out, to use `ALTER` statements to reduce column length in DB for LUW, this is not the case in DB2 for z/OS as of version 10.

According to [this table](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_altertable.htm), only data type changes from `VARCHAR(n)` to `VARCHAR(n+x)` are supported, which is a bummer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reduce the length of a column. To achieve this affect you should

- create a new table with your data and with the attribute that you want.
- Delete old table
- Rename the new table

If you want to increase the length, it is possible with `ALTER` command

```
 ALTER TABLE temp
      ALTER COLUMN col1
      SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(60)
```

Comment: ... Except you can use the `ALTER TABLE` command to _shorten_ the column as well.  Why would you expect that a command that could _increase_ the length wouldn't be usable to _decrease_ it as well?  Your syntax is correct, and should be the statement he needs.  Although, of course, data may be truncated.